# node.js: form HTTP Authentication with request module fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying get page behind the login form with node.js request module.

'username' and 'password' are the names of fields of that form, 'login.php?do=login'  is a form action. Doing that I don't get any headers and status codes but only [Error: no auth mechanism defined] message in console.

```
var request = require('request'),

var options = {
    'auth' : {
    'username':'name',
    'password':'pass'
},
url: 'http://example.com/login.php?do=login',
headers: {
    "User-Agent":"user-agent"
    }
}

request.post(options, function(err,res,body) {
if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
console.log('headers :', res.headers);
console.log('status code :', res.statusCode);
console.log($('body').text());
});
```

How could I investigate this? Which way it can be "sniffered" or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request module's `auth` option is to handle [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Most likely the page you try to load does not use BAA, but uses a simple form with a post request. To send form data with [`requests`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var options = {
    url: '...',
    headers: { ... },
    method: 'POST',
    formData: {
        'username':'name',
        'password':'pass'
    }
}
```

Comment: big thanx. doing this way I get headers and status code : 302  I guess it redirect me where I want. Its strange, but I have not seen nothing about formData object in request docs.  Thanx again.

Comment: could you drop a sight to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381531/using-node-js-request-module-to-get-a-page-with-filecookiestore). tnx.