# using node.js request module to get a page with FileCookieStore

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

I'm trying to use node.js request to fetch a page from a webserver we use.
I retrieve the cookies from the results of the previous request,
and now trying send them to the profile page as request argument.

```
var request = require('request'),
fileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore');

var j = request.jar(new fileCookieStore("./cookie.json"));
var options = {
    url     : 'http://example.com/site/page.php?u=1234',
    jar     : j,
    headers : {
        "User-Agent":"user_agent"
    }
};

request(options, function(err,res,body) {
if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
    }
console.log('body');
});
```

cookie file looks like that:

```
[{
    "domain": "www.example.com",
    "expirationDate": 1482144640.897115,
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "password",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "8ff31b0edcf85b72b20469044dafc373",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.example.com",
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "sessionhash",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "13d0e4ff1bdeefbe118df4ad04c81a2e",
    "id": 2
  }]
```

and there's no luck. body in console log says that I'm still not logged in. How can I do that?

Comment: What if the session stored in the cookie is expired?

Comment: You could use Fiddler to capture network traffic and debug

Comment: @hege_hegedus  -  this helps a bit :      var j = request.jar();
    j.setCookie(request.cookie('key1=value1','key2=value2');                         but only for first login. For the first time it log me in succesfully, the second attempt in a five second fails, I am not logged again. Something wrong with cookies, I think. Sadness.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass j object, the one that you passed in jar method in your next request.
I do something similar at my work

from request website:

> jar - If true, remember cookies for future use (or define your custom cookie jar; see examples section)

https://github.com/request/request

Comment: thanx, I'll try to do this soon.